# How to replicate my google docs format into latex?

Tags: document-classes

I have a document in google docs that I was hoping to replicate in latex including font size and border-spacing. I looked through the templates but could only find one template on overleaf called `Sample Policy Memo for Cornell INFO 1200` https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/sample-policy-memo-for-cornell-info-1200/kybzqhsxjgjk from the section on `formal-letters`. I still am not able to get it to look like my google docs (link below) and was hoping someone could help me out.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{texMemo} % originally by Rob Oakes; adapted by Alice Chen
\usepackage{mathptmx}

Title\\
Name (email)

\begin{document}
\maketitle

{\LARGE \textbf{Introduction}}\\
Some text for introduction.\\

{\LARGE \textbf{Research Question}}\\
Some text for research question.\\

{\LARGE \textbf{Methodology}}\\
Some text for methodology.\\

\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Google Docs https://docs.google.com/document/d/15AXu65Itz5TxXLLxGOKg4AZsQs6bQX_TkV7GFIImtfQ/edit?usp=sharing

EDIT: I have edited the code but it doesnt show title and name it only shows email.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{texMemo} % originally by Rob Oakes; adapted by Alice Chen
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\email{email}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Introduction}
Some text for introduction.

\section*{Introduction}
Some text for research question.

\section*{Introduction}
Some text for methodology.

\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where can the community get access to the `texMemo` document class that you're using?

Comment: @Werner sorry I forgot to mention that the template was on overleaf. I have edited my post.

Comment: Remember to put yourself in our shoes. All I see is that "it's on Overleaf." Where...? Can you problem a link to some template?

Comment: @Werner sorry I have included the link to the template

Comment: You want `\title{Title}` and `\author{Name}` and possibly `\email{email}` where you currently have `Title\\Name (email)`.  `\maketitle` is the command that will take those and weave it into your title.

Comment: And you want `\section*{}` where you have `{\LARGE \textbf{}}` and don't use `\\` to break lines outside environments such as `tabular`.

Comment: Rather than asking 'how to make my document look like this' it would be better to ask something specific. For example, 'how can I make the font size 12pt?' or 14pt or whatever, or 'how can I get margins of 15mm all round on A5 paper?'

Comment: @Teepeemm those code is giving me error missing begin document at line \email

Comment: @cfr those code is giving me error missing begin document at line \email

Comment: If (as in the comment) your file gives an error for the `\email` command, that means that the class doesn't define the `\email` command.  If (as in the body of the edit) your file doesn't show the title and name but only the email, that means that the class defines `\maketitle` to do so.  Either way, I think it might be time to stop using that class and switch to something that comes as a default.  I would recommend `article`.  And then ask us how to implement a specific feature like cfr mentioned, not "make it like google docs".

Comment: If the class only shows an email (sensible for a memo - it might have a subject and date, but memos don't usually have titles) and you want a title, it probably isn't the right class as @Teepeemm says. It sounds as if you want something much closer to a standard `article` so `article`, the Koma-script version or similar would probably be more suitable.